# How can I record the log of starting a program on command prompt

Tags: firefox, cmd

I was wondering if you could tell me how I can get a log file for opening a program via command prompt. Firefox is not working and I can't figure out how to see why it is failing.

Originally I was using the command:

```
    start firefox.exe /L:d > "log.txt"
```

Obviously this isn't the right code.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably off topic for SO. Did you try troubleshooting with [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: Thanks. My apologies for being a slightly off topic. I didn't realize and so next time I will find a more appropriate discussion board. I'm technically trying to fix someone else's computer so I'm trying to figure out the easiest and least intrusive way of solving the problem which is why I didn't safe mode it (Though that would probably be a logical step in most debugging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree this should be migrated to SuperUser, but in the meantime, it doesn't look like firefox.exe actually logs anything to stdout to begin with.  See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments for details.

Comment: hmmm...thanks for the link. If that is the case, how would you get debugging information for a program failure when trying to start it?

Comment: In short, that's entirely up to the developer.  They may log events in the event log, they may output to stdout, they may create their own logfile somewhere, or they may choose to be completely opaque about it and not offer any insight short of hooking up a debugger (and even then, good luck debugging without symbols).  For Firefox in particular, I'm not aware of any way to see what it's doing, and your original question doesn't specify what "not working" means.